# When I save, it doesn't automatically hot reload Flutter Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[My Android Studio Setings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSJ4B.png)

I want it to automatically hot reload when I save, it was working before.

```
Flutter Doctor

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale tr-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

I didn't make any changes to the settings, but suddenly it lost its automatic hot reload feature when I saved. How can I fix it?

Comment: I meet the same issue too, the perform hot reload on save not works on Android Studio any more, I have to click hot reload manually, but vs code works fine

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Stack Overflow.

Hot reload will work when you hit the file <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> in android studio.
I prefer VSCode for coding and debugging in flutter.

Comment: I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, thank you

Comment: Reinstalling your Android Studio is exhausting. Try to invalidate and restart instead. `File > Invalidate Caches... > Invalidate Cache and Restart`